# I3 can't properly use the clipboard

Tags: i3, clipboard

Alright this is a problem I've been facing for months. Im not sure if this is a problem with i3 or urxvt. I can't get the clipboard to work properly. I can copy text from my browser and paste it on the terminal but NOT the other way around. For some reason hitting Ctrl-Shift-C allows me to copy text between terminals but not to my browser. I installed clipster and saw that when I copy something on Firefox it goes to the CLIPBOARD clipboard whereas when I copy something from the terminal it goes into the PRIMARY clipboard. I also tried tosynchronize them by adding the following to my xinitrc file:

```
autocutsel -fork -selection CLIPBOARD
autocutsel -fork -selection PRIMARY
```

but it didn't help, what gives? How do I fix this?

Comment: In urxvt try ctrl-alt-c/v. `man urxvt` describes other options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr highlighting anything will copy, and middle clicking will paste.**

This method appears to be using the Primary clipboard which works in both directions (browser <-> urxvt).

Of course this is not ideal, because you cannot highlight text and replace it by pasting, but it does work at the most basic level.

There are some details in [this doc](https://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html).